# dplyr filter with $%in%$ using a filter on the dot

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to filter based on a nested dplyr chain. Similar to a partition or window I guess.

In the example code below I wanted to create duplicates of new field 'blah' but `crossing()` seems to dedup. So for illustration purposes and without picking another r battle, please pretend that mydiamonds has duplicates in blah.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydiamonds <- diamonds %>% mutate(color = as.character(color)) %>% crossing(blah = c(1,2,2,2,3)) # if this worked as desired to illustrate my need then there would be duplicate rows for blah, but crossing seems to dedup :(

# wanted to do something like this, similar to sql 'in' syntax
blah2_diamonds <- mydiamonds %>% filter(color %in% . %>% filter(blah == 2) %>% pull(color) %>% unique)
```

But this gives error:

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"
ℹ Input `..1` is `color %in% . %>% filter(blah == 2) %>% pull(color) %>% unique`.
```

In other words, how can I filter mydiamonds to only include colors where blah == 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`, one option would be `cur_data` (which may also work if the data is grouped) to return the data, then return the `unique` 'color' where the 'blah value is 2.  It is better to containerize in a block with `{}` or `()`

```
mydiamonds %>% 
    filter(color %in% {
            cur_data() %>%
               filter(blah == 2) %>% 
               pull(color) %>%
               unique})
```

Or another option is to place the data i.e. `.` within a `{}` and then apply the second set of nested chain within `filter`

```
mydiamonds %>%
     filter(color %in% 
         ({.} %>% 
            filter(blah == 2) %>%
            pull(color) %>%
            unique))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's new syntax. What's cur_data()? Is that just the dot?

Comment: Yes, it is effectively the `.`. From [`?cur_data`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html): *"gives the current data for the current group (excluding grouping variables)"*.